# Is there a way to get the tax schedule name from any API?

Tags: netsuite

I've been reading through the [various browsers](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/script/record/item.html) trying to figure out how to fetch the tax schedule name for a given item. I see that with the Records Browser I can get an item with a `taxschedule` property, but when I retrieve an item with the `N/search` module in a RESTlet, the `taxschedule` property only has the value of its internal id.

Is there any way for me to get the name of a tax schedule via some API for a NetSuite account with advanced taxes enabled? By name I mean the label/product/description/whatever property gives the some descriptive value of the tax schedule instead of just the internal id.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the N/search module, I assume at some point you use the Result.getValue method.  If this is true, instead use the Result.getText method.

You can use a conditional (ternary) operator like this to get the Text if it exists or get the Value (if the text does not exist).  You might have to update the test for null based on how the field is in your instance...

```
var entity = (result.getText({name: 'entity'}) != null) ? result.getText({name: 'entity'}) : result.getValue({name: 'entity'});
var entity = (result.getText(resultSet.columns[1])!= null) ? result.getText(resultSet.columns[1]) : result.getValue(resultSet.columns[1])
```